# Accessing a property from an extended class

Tags: php

```
<?php

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    protected $foo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = '123';
    }   

    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the `BaseController` and I want to declare `foo` as 123, but can I get the `foo` variable in the controller which I have extended from this basecontroller, can you help?

```
public function detail($action) 
{
    return $this->foo;
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific issue you encountered?

Comment: Of course, you can. But, What's your problem ??

Comment: when i retrieve the variable in the controller which extends from the base, it is empty... there is no any error msg.

Comment: Are you overriding the constructor in the controller that extends `BaseController`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you extend the controller, I imagine that you're currently doing this:

```
<?php

class NewController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Do something here.
    }

    public function detail($action)
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}
```

You see how the `__construct` method is being overwritten. You can easily fix this by adding `parent::__construct()` to the beginning of the method, so you'll have this:

```
<?php

class NewController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Do something here.
    }

    public function detail($action)
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per docs: 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

> Note: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class
>   defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, **a call to
>   parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required.**

As you are doing some work in your parent class constructor, you must invoke it directly in your subclass too (even this would be to only thing you do in child's constructor). I.e.:

```
class ChildController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

...
```